# Can't run a script

Tags: linux, ssh, vi, synology

I tried to create a script in linux, on a Synology server over SSH

so I wrote a file test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is a test"
```

I saved the file.
after that I did

```
chmod 755 test.sh
```

the I did

```
./test.sh
```

then i got this error

```
-ash "./test.sh" is not found
```

the file was created in

```
/root
```

I don't understand

Comment: `not fout`? `not found`, perhaps?

Comment: Try `/root/test.sh`.

Comment: This could mean that `/bin/bash` does not exist.

Comment: Indeed bin/bash does not exists

Comment: What does `/bin/bash /path/to/test.sh` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell (ash?) is trying to execute your script and is getting an `ENOENT` (no such file or directory) error code back. This can refer to the script itself, but in this case it refers to the interpreter named in the `#!` line.

That is, `/bin/bash` does not exist and that's why the script couldn't be started.

Workaround: Install bash or (if you don't need any bash specific features) change the first line to `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the quirks with hash bang programs. If the *interpreter* is not found (i.e. the program interpreting the script), you don't get a completely useful error like `/bin/bash: no such file`, but a completely useless and misleading `test.sh: not found`.

If this isn't in the *[Unix Hater's Handbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix-Haters_Handbook)*, it should be. :-)

You can either use `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/path/to/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (which searches PATH for bash).